# Residual bounds for $\sum_{n} a_n cos(2\pi x n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Assume $ a_n\in O(n^{-k} )$ and $ a_n\geq 0$. Simply bounding the cosine term by 1 we get that

$$
|\sum_{n> m} a_n \cos(2\pi x n)|< C m^{-k+1}
$$
(for $ k> 1$).

However, this doesn't exploit oscillation.  For example,  for $ x =1/2$ we can easily improve the bound to $ C m^{-k} $ by first bounding the sum of each two consecutive terms.

For irrational $ x $, the cosine terms are symmetrically distributed around $0$, so I could imagine that we can get the same bound as for $ x=1/2$, but I cannot prove it.

For rational $ x $, I don't really have a good idea of what is going on.

**Question**: What are optimal bounds on the residual for rational or irrational $ x $ and how are they proved?

(A small probably irrelevant note: considering the sum as a sum of functions on $ x\in [0,1) $ and using orthogonality of the wave functions,  one can show that the mean square (over $ x$) residual is $ m^{-k+1/2} $.)

Comment: so... what is the question?

Comment: Good point.  I worked it out more clearly in the edit

Comment: Better bounds can be derived from applying partial summation, but any tight upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(2\pi x n)$ clearly depends on $x$, obviously. If $x=0$, there is no oscillation to exploit at all.